# How to edit a running program in GDB when it crashes/segfaults

Tags: c, gdb

I am trying to change variable values in GDB. I am not sure how to do it correctly. I have searched on google but could not get the correct answer.

here is what i am trying

```
(gdb) run set number = 4   **<---- here i try to set the number to 4** 
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y

Starting program: /u/data/u3/msehgal/Desktop/CS252/lab1-src/debug set number = 4
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=5, argv=0x7fffffffe4f8) at public.c:19
19    printf ("Starting tests.\n");
(gdb) n
Starting tests.
20    fflush (stdout);
(gdb) n
22    initialize_array ();
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400ce8 in initialize_array () at public.c:40
40      numbers[i] = i + 1;
(gdb) print numbers
$3 = (int *) 0x0  **<---- on re-run the number is still 0**
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure the variable you are trying to set is in current scope.

Than you should use

```
(gdb) set variable i = val
```

You can check to see whether it is updated with

```
(gdb) p i
```

I think you are not using `variable` above.

Extract from [this site](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_118.html)

> Because the set command has many subcommands that can conflict with
>   the names of program variables, it is a good idea to use the set
>   variable command instead of just set.

Comment: numbers is an array so you should set something like numbers[i]=val; numbers=i is an invalid assignment anyway. so my suggestion first find value of i using p i. than set number[value you found]=to value you require

Answer (score 0):

The result looks like that the variable `numbers` was not initialised as an array so the address was 0x00, and your program attempted to use the uninitialised array, so it resulted in segmentation fault.

In your gdb case, you made several mistakes:

1. the syntax you used is incorrect; you should use: `set var number=4`
2. you set the variable value at the very beginning, which only works if the scope of the variable is global; you should confirm the variable scope in order to set the value to the right variable.
3. you set value to variable `number` instead of `numbers`, so the `numbers` wouldn't change.

Comment: You can't set number=4; as evident from above numbers is an array

Comment: You are right if the number is the typo of numbers.